# error C4716: function : must return a value

Tags: visual-c++, pthreads

So I am trying to use pthread libraries for Visual C++(2012) and I get this error `error C4716: 'print_message' : must return a value`
Here's the code

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include "pthread.h"
using namespace std;

void* print_message(void *)
{
    cout << "Threading\n";
}

int main() 
{
    pthread_t t1;

    pthread_create(&t1, NULL, print_message, NULL);
    cout << "Hello";

    void* result;
    pthread_join(t1,&result);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add  `return NULL;`  to `print_message`. I'll bet you need to name the argument too.